# Is there a specific feature/service in AWS to pull reports on unused R53 domains, ELBs and EIPs

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to pull a report of unused Route 53 domains, Elastic Load Balancers and Elastic IPs on a monthly basis. I am just trying to learn if there are any specific tool to do that within AWS.

Comment: No, there is no automatic report that can do this. It also depends on what you mean by "unused".

Comment: Basically, the idea is to find out Data Transfer Costs to find Idle R53, ELBs and EIPs in an AWS account

Comment: Route 53 responds to DNS requests. So, if there are no requests to resolve a domain name, it could be deemed 'unused'. The only Data Transfer cost for Route 53 would be responses to such requests, but I don't think this is charged.. Similarly, Elastic Load Balancers only respond to requests. If nothing is sending traffic to them, they won't respond and therefore there will be no Data Transfer cost (but there will still be the hourly charge). Elastic IP addresses do not incur Data Transfer costs -- they simply associate an IP address with a resource. Does that help answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you @JohnRotenstein